# Young aged belivers and new believers

Tags: discussion

My concern is with younger belivers that want answers to simple question but require long logistic answers that are too involved for their understanding.  We have a young man right now (12 or 13) that I feel in my hearts wants and needs some answers but his questions or his implications of the questions are so out of reach it is very hard to answer in simple and basic terms.  Also he seems to be very concerned with his reputation. Should younger members even be granted a reputation as they find this as being unaccepted?

My concern comes if we don't  answer we are showing no support for his spiritual growth which could turn him away from the things of God.  His faith seems genuine but of course his inquisitiveness is that of a child.

I certainly appreciate this site and the dedicated moderators as well as others Christian's that put much time and effort into questions and answers but my heart also cries out for new and younger aged belivers that seem to want answers now.

Has there ever been thought of dedicating a site just for them?  I understand why this would probably be a impossibility but perhaps they could be let down gently.  Perhaps a  "soft" written explanation  that their questions should be found with their Sunday school teachers, mothers and fathers or even their own Pastors.    Just a short note with a heart felt concern for their needs in their walk with Christ should be adequate and forbade any bitterness they may find with CSE.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: See also: [Why can't I ask for personal advice?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6018/21576)

Comment: I'm rather certain all us mods are under 40 or thereabouts and we've done youth ministry and scout leadership.  We could improve the message nobody probably reads any more on the sidebar of the site.  Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  The reason I brought this up was because some of the responses seem harsh for 12-15 year olds.   I have read your terms of service and tried to read most of the others that have been pointed out to me.  All are direct and very clear for an adult.  Adults should be able to control their emotions  rationally.  Children on the other hand need a more gentle touch especially when they have  their hearts turned towards our Saviour.  Do you remember your excitement when you were saved?  Pretty grand, huh?

Comment: You will have my support as I know this will be handled with the utmost respect concerning all.  Thank you for your time and listening to my concern

Answer (score 4):

1. Uses in the EU must be at least 16, or in the rest of the world at least 13 to even legally sigun up for and use the SE network of sites. See the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#age).
2. All pastoral advice questions whether asked from youth or adults are already off topic. We already have a policy [of leaving a polite but firm comment directing them to proper channels](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/30). See also the [pastoral-advice-questions](/questions/tagged/pastoral-advice-questions) meta site tag for more discussion relating to this type of question and how we have opted to handle them across the board.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that open forums on the Interwebs may not be not the best places to foster spiritual growth.

These are forums for mature, calm discussion.  Anyone of any age who is capable of asking, discussing, and answering questions in that manner should be welcome to it.  That requires some self-judgement.